# mvc 5 - passing a list of checked items to the controller

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

So as the title says I'm trying to pass a list with checked items from view to controller.

This is what my view looks like :

```
    @model List<MyApp.Models.MyClassObject>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

</head>
<body>
    <div>

        <form action="" method="post">
            <table>

                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i += 3)
                {
                    if (Model.Count - i <= 3) { break; }
                    else
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.HiddenFor(Modelitem => Model[i].checked)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(Modelitem => Model[i].url)
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].checked)
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].checked)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.HiddenFor(Modelitem => Model[i+1].checked)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(Modelitem => Model[i+1].url)
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i + 1].checked)
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i + 1].url)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.HiddenFor(Modelitem => Model[i+2].checked)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(Modelitem => Model[i+2].url)
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i + 2].checked)
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i + 2].url)
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    }


                }

            </table>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Send" />
        </form>


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

To explain this a little bit, i typed out the hiddenfields in hoping that the list passed won't be null ( as it is right now )

MyClassObject looks like this :

```
public class MyClassObject
{
    public string url;
    public bool checked;
    public MyClassObject(string item)
    {
        url = item;
    }
    public MyClassObject()
    {

    }
}
```

Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Something(List<MyClassObject> items)
        {
          //blabla
        }
```

So again, my problem is that when i press submit i recive a list of X items ( x being the number of items shown on the page no matter if checked or not ) with both "checked" and "url" being the default value (false and null ).
Thank you !

Comment: You have multiple problems. No idea what you trying to do with your `for` loop and the `break` statement - indexers need to start at zero and be consecutive so it need to be `@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)` an delete the `break`. And your model has only fields, not properties so no values can be set by the `DefautlModelBinder` and then you have a hidden input for the `checked` property so it would only ever post back the original value. And finally you need to delete everything in the 2nd and 3rd `<td>` elements

Comment: If you wanting to display 3 items per row, then use css (wrap the elements in a div with `float: left; width: 33%;`) Your not using tabular data so using a `<table>` element is not the correct approach

Answer (score -1):

convert to IList  as shown

```
@model IList<MyApp.Models.MyClassObject>
```

and controller method like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Something(IEnumerable<MyClassObject> items)
{
  //blabla
}
```

use

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{}
```

instead of form or give the action to the form because it will render it like this

```
<form action="/Controller/Action" method="post"><
```